# CSS, WordPress, PHP issue regarding blog creation

Tags: php, wordpress

I am very new to WordPress and I am having this issue now.
My code displays all images and blog contents but the problem here is, if there are no images to display the content gets auto aligned since there is CSS for this class.

I need the blog post should get the `width:620` if there are no images to post and `width:420` if there are images in loop. Help needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you inspect your element using "F12" key

Comment: *"My code displays all images..."* <- what code? Could you post it? Code => answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You coould add some classes to div containing post content, like for example with-media and no-media.

To find if post has any media, you can use this code:

```
$media = get_attached_media( 'image' );
 if (is_array($media) && count($media) > 0) {
$classname = 'with-media';
} else {
  $classname = 'no-media';
}
```

then print it in div:

```
<div class="some-class another-class <?php echo $classname; ?>"...
```

now, when you have it, you can add css definition to style.css:

```
.no-media { width: 620px; }
.with-media {width: 420px; }
```